# The path '' is not valid for the 'dbDacFx' provider with ARM templates SAT Sitecore Deployment

Tags: azure, paas, azure-resource-manager

im trying to deploy "vanilla" Sitecore using the topology "XM" to create in Azure CD and CM PaaS servers

ive encountered many issues while trying to get this working, but the most recent deployment error im getting now is below...

> The path '' is not valid for the 'dbDacFx' provider.

im using the Sitecore Azure Toolkit v1.1 for Sitecore 8.2 update 5.

All of the resources deploy correctly, but once this completes after around 15 minutes i get this error. I understand this is in relation to restoring the databases using the DACPAC files but i dont understand which path its related to.

my deploy parameters JSON template is valid and i have checked that the azure storage SAS tokens for the SCWDP (sitecore web deploy packages) are all working

any help is most appricated

JGilmartin